# Change selection mode of combobox dynamically

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs6

I have a combobox with `multiSelect: true`

For some condition, I want to change is to single selected and then again back to multiselect for another condition.

I tried-

```
if(condition1)
{
    combo1.multiSelect = false;
    combo1.updateLayout();
}
```

Even after adding this, I am able to select multiple values from combox.
Is there anything else I need to add to this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is not enough. I looked into the source, and it seems that you also need to change the ["mode"](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.selection.DataViewModel.html#cfg-mode) for the "combo.pickerSelectionModel" property. So the final code should look something like this:

```
combo.multiSelect = !currentMultiselect;                       
combo.pickerSelectionModel.setSelectionMode(combo.multiSelect ? 'SIMPLE' : 'SINGLE');
```

Here you have a [sample fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1p7r).